# pyspark approxQuantile function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe with these columns `id`, `price`, `timestamp`.

I would like to find median value grouped by `id`.

I am using this code to find it but it's giving me this error.

```python
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameStatFunctions as statFunc
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("id")
median = statFunc.approxQuantile("price",
                                 [0.5],
                                 0) \
                 .over(windowSpec)

return df.withColumn("Median", median)
```

Is it not possible to use `DataFrameStatFunctions` to fill values in new column?

```python
TypeError: unbound method approxQuantile() must be called with DataFrameStatFunctions instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Well, indeed it is **not** possible to use `approxQuantile` to fill values in a new dataframe column, but this is not why you are getting this error. Unfortunately, the whole underneath story is a rather frustrating one, as [I have argued](https://www.nodalpoint.com/spark-classification/) that is the case with many Spark (especially PySpark) features and their lack of adequate documentation.

To start with, there is not one, but **two** `approxQuantile` methods; the [first one](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.approxQuantile) is part of the standard DataFrame class, i.e. you don't need to import DataFrameStatFunctions:

```python
spark.version
# u'2.1.1'

sampleData = [("bob","Developer",125000),("mark","Developer",108000),("carl","Tester",70000),("peter","Developer",185000),("jon","Tester",65000),("roman","Tester",82000),("simon","Developer",98000),("eric","Developer",144000),("carlos","Tester",75000),("henry","Developer",110000)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(sampleData, schema=["Name","Role","Salary"])
df.show()
# +------+---------+------+ 
# |  Name|     Role|Salary|
# +------+---------+------+
# |   bob|Developer|125000| 
# |  mark|Developer|108000|
# |  carl|   Tester| 70000|
# | peter|Developer|185000|
# |   jon|   Tester| 65000|
# | roman|   Tester| 82000|
# | simon|Developer| 98000|
# |  eric|Developer|144000|
# |carlos|   Tester| 75000|
# | henry|Developer|110000|
# +------+---------+------+

med = df.approxQuantile("Salary", [0.5], 0.25) # no need to import DataFrameStatFunctions
med
# [98000.0]
```

[The second one](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions) is part of `DataFrameStatFunctions`, but if you use it as you do, you get the error you report:

```python
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameStatFunctions as statFunc
med2 = statFunc.approxQuantile( "Salary", [0.5], 0.25)
# TypeError: unbound method approxQuantile() must be called with DataFrameStatFunctions instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

because the correct usage is

```python
med2 = statFunc(df).approxQuantile( "Salary", [0.5], 0.25)
med2
# [82000.0]
```

although you won't be able to find a simple example in the PySpark documentation about this (it took me some time to figure it out myself)... The best part? The two values are **not equal**:

```python
med == med2
# False
```

I suspect this is due to the non-deterministic algorithm used (after all, it is supposed to be an *approximate* median), and even if you re-run the commands with the same toy data you may get different values (and different from the ones I report here) - I suggest to experiment a little to get the feeling...

But, as I already said, this is not the reason why you cannot use `approxQuantile` to fill values in a new dataframe column - even if you use the correct syntax, you will get a different error:

```python
df2 = df.withColumn('median_salary', statFunc(df).approxQuantile( "Salary", [0.5], 0.25))
# AssertionError: col should be Column
```

Here, `col` refers to the second argument of the `withColumn` operation, i.e. the `approxQuantile` one, and the error message says that it is not a `Column` type - indeed, it is a list:

```python
type(statFunc(df).approxQuantile( "Salary", [0.5], 0.25))
# list
```

So, when filling column values, Spark expects arguments of type `Column`, and you cannot use lists; here is an example of creating a new column with mean values per Role instead of median ones:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql import Window

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(df['Role'])
df2 = df.withColumn('mean_salary', func.mean(df['Salary']).over(windowSpec))
df2.show()
# +------+---------+------+------------------+
# |  Name|     Role|Salary|       mean_salary| 
# +------+---------+------+------------------+
# |  carl|   Tester| 70000|           73000.0| 
# |   jon|   Tester| 65000|           73000.0|
# | roman|   Tester| 82000|           73000.0|
# |carlos|   Tester| 75000|           73000.0|
# |   bob|Developer|125000|128333.33333333333|
# |  mark|Developer|108000|128333.33333333333| 
# | peter|Developer|185000|128333.33333333333| 
# | simon|Developer| 98000|128333.33333333333| 
# |  eric|Developer|144000|128333.33333333333|
# | henry|Developer|110000|128333.33333333333| 
# +------+---------+------+------------------+
```

which works because, contrary to `approxQuantile`, `mean` returns a `Column`:

```python
type(func.mean(df['Salary']).over(windowSpec))
# pyspark.sql.column.Column
```

Answer (score 9):

#### Calculating quantiles in groups (aggregated) example

As aggregated function is missing for groups, I'm adding an example of constructing function call by name (`percentile_approx` for this case) :

```
from pyspark.sql.column import Column, _to_java_column, _to_seq

def from_name(sc, func_name, *params):
    """
       create call by function name 
    """
    callUDF = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.functions.callUDF
    func = callUDF(func_name, _to_seq(sc, *params, _to_java_column))
    return Column(func)
```

Apply `percentile_approx` function in groupBy:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

# build percentile_approx function call by name: 
target = from_name(sc, "percentile_approx", [f.col("salary"), f.lit(0.95)])


# load dataframe for persons data 
# with columns "person_id", "group_id" and "salary"
persons = spark.read.parquet( ... )

# apply function for each group
persons.groupBy("group_id").agg(
    target.alias("target")).show()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are fine with aggregation instead of the window function, there is also the option to use a pandas_udf. They are not as fast as pure Spark though. Here is an adapted example from the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=agg#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)], ("id", "price")
)

@pandas_udf("double", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def median_udf(v):
    return v.median()

df.groupby("id").agg(median_udf(df["price"])).show()
```

Comment: Will pd.cut give us the same result as approxQuantile?

Comment: No. If you look at its examples, it does something completely different. Anyway, as ionathan pointed out, there is no need to fall back on pandas udfs anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Since PySpark 3.1.0  the [`percentile_approx`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx.html) function has been introduced that solves this problem.

The function `percentile_approx` returns a list, thus you need to slice the first element.

As in:

```
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("id")
df.withColumn("Median", F.percentile_approx("price", [0.5]).over(windowSpec)[0])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for mentioning percentile_approx. Since there was no way to use approxQuantiles in a groupBy result, I was writing a for loop around it. Estimated 55 hours for the whole run, which was reduced to 15 mins by this percentile_approx. I compared the values I got from both - both are same!