# Median / quantiles within PySpark groupBy

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, median

I would like to calculate group quantiles on a Spark dataframe (using PySpark). Either an approximate or exact result would be fine. I prefer a solution that I can use within the context of `groupBy` / `agg`, so that I can mix it with other PySpark aggregate functions. If this is not possible for some reason, a different approach would be fine as well.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432843/how-to-find-median-and-quantiles-using-spark) is related but does not indicate how to use `approxQuantile` as an aggregate function.

I also have access to the `percentile_approx` Hive UDF but I don't know how to use it as an aggregate function.

For the sake of specificity, suppose I have the following dataframe:

```python
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

sc = SparkContext()    

df = sc.parallelize([
    ['A', 1],
    ['A', 2],
    ['A', 3],
    ['B', 4],
    ['B', 5],
    ['B', 6],
]).toDF(('grp', 'val'))

df_grp = df.groupBy('grp').agg(f.magic_percentile('val', 0.5).alias('med_val'))
df_grp.show()
```

Expected result:

```
+----+-------+
| grp|med_val|
+----+-------+
|   A|      2|
|   B|      5|
+----+-------+
```

Comment: I think you might be able to roll your own in this instance using the underlying rdd and an algorithm for computing distributed quantiles e.g. [here](https://dataorigami.net/blogs/napkin-folding/19055451-percentile-and-quantile-estimation-of-big-data-the-t-digest) and links therein. In fact, the github they link to has some pyspark examples.

Comment: [How to use approxQuantile by group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53548964/6910411)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

I guess you don't need it anymore. But will leave it here for future generations (i.e. me next week when I forget).

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

grp_window = Window.partitionBy('grp')
magic_percentile = F.expr('percentile_approx(val, 0.5)')

df.withColumn('med_val', magic_percentile.over(grp_window))
```

Or to address exactly your question, this also works:

```
df.groupBy('grp').agg(magic_percentile.alias('med_val'))
```

And as a bonus, you can pass an array of percentiles:

```
quantiles = F.expr('percentile_approx(val, array(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))')
```

And you'll get a list in return.

Comment: Very clean answer. Do you know how can it be done using Pandas UDF (a.k.a. Vectorized UDFs) too?

Comment: @CesareIurlaro, I've only wrapped it in a UDF. Never tried with a Pandas one

Comment: Would you mind to try? Performace really should shine there: https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html

Comment: With Spark 3.1.0 it is now possible to use `percentile_approx` directly in PySpark groupby aggregations: `df.groupBy("key").agg(percentile_approx("value", 0.5, lit(1000000)).alias("median"))` https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx.html

Comment: @kael or @chris-a can we get 00schneider's comment added to this answer? This is the simplest & best solution now that it is built in to `pyspark.sql.functions`

Comment: what is the difference between using `expr('percentile(val, 0.5)')` vs `expr('percentile_approx(val, 0.5)')`  ?

Comment: @thentangler: the former is an exact percentile, which is not a scalable operation for large datasets, and the latter is approximate but scalable.

Answer (score 16):

Since you have access to `percentile_approx`, one simple solution would be to use it in a `SQL` command:

```python
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df.registerTempTable("df")
df2 = sqlContext.sql("select grp, percentile_approx(val, 0.5) as med_val from df group by grp")
```

Comment: This works, but I prefer a solution that I can use within `groupBy` / `agg` at the PySpark level (so that I can easily mix it with other PySpark aggregate functions).

Comment: @abeboparebop I do not beleive it's possible to only use `groupBy` and `agg`, however, to use a window-based approach should also work.

Comment: I have clarified my ideal solution in the question. Clearly this answer does the job, but it's not quite what I want. I'll leave the question open for some time to see if a cleaner answer comes up.

Answer (score 15):

(**UPDATE**: now it *is* possible, see accepted answer above)

---

Unfortunately, and to the best of my knowledge, it seems that it is not possible to do this with "pure" PySpark commands (the solution by Shaido provides a workaround with SQL), and the reason is very elementary: in contrast with other aggregate functions, such as `mean`, `approxQuantile` does not return a `Column` type, but a *list*.

Let's see a quick example with your sample data:

```python
spark.version
# u'2.2.0'

import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameStatFunctions as statFunc

# aggregate with mean works OK:
df_grp_mean = df.groupBy('grp').agg(func.mean(df['val']).alias('mean_val'))
df_grp_mean.show()
# +---+--------+ 
# |grp|mean_val|
# +---+--------+
# |  B|     5.0|
# |  A|     2.0|
# +---+--------+

# try aggregating by median:
df_grp_med = df.groupBy('grp').agg(statFunc(df).approxQuantile('val', [0.5], 0.1))
# AssertionError: all exprs should be Column

# mean aggregation is a Column, but median is a list:

type(func.mean(df['val']))
# pyspark.sql.column.Column

type(statFunc(df).approxQuantile('val', [0.5], 0.1))
# list
```

I doubt that a window-based approach will make any difference, since as I said the underlying reason is a very elementary one.

See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287832/pyspark-approxquantile-function/45506281#45506281) for some more details.

Answer (score 9):

It seems to be completely solved by `pyspark >= 3.1.0` using `percentile_approx`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func    

df.groupBy("grp").agg(func.percentile_approx("val", 0.5).alias("median"))
```

For further information see:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx.html

Comment: From version 3.4+ (and also already in 3.3.1) the median function is directly available
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e170a2eb236a376b036730b5d63371e753f1d947/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py#L633

Answer (score 8):

The most simple way to do this with `pyspark==2.4.5` is:

```
df \
    .groupby('grp') \
    .agg(expr('percentile(val, array(0.5))')[0].alias('p50')) \
    .show()
```

output:

```
|grp|p50|
+---+---+
|  B|5.0|
|  A|2.0|
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

problem of "percentile_approx(val, 0.5)":
if e.g. range is [1,2,3,4] this function returns 2 (as median) the function below returns 2.5:

```
import statistics

median_udf = F.udf(lambda x: statistics.median(x) if bool(x) else None, DoubleType())

... .groupBy('something').agg(median_udf(F.collect_list(F.col('value'))).alias('median'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably all above answers may not give the right answer when there are even number of entries in the group. To make it general and make it work in those case, an averaging of the 50th percentile and the next value would be the best.

```
df_grp = df.groupBy('grp').agg(
  F.percentile_approx('val', 0.5).alias('med_val'),
  ((F.percentile_approx('val', 0.5)+ F.percentile_approx('val', 0.500000000001))*.5).alias('med_val2')
  )
df_grp.show()
```

In the above code, `med_val2` gives you the correct median even when there is even number of entries in the group. The number 0.500000000001 is just chosen it is slightly above 0.5 and so that it works for even large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

**Spark 3.4+** has [**`median`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.median.html#pyspark.sql.functions.median) (exact median) which can be accessed directly in PySpark:

```py
F.median('val')
```

With your example dataframe:

```py
df.groupBy('grp').agg(F.median('val')).show()
# +---+-----------+
# |grp|median(val)|
# +---+-----------+
# |  A|        2.0|
# |  B|        5.0|
# +---+-----------+
```

---

Other quantiles (**quartiles, percentiles**, etc.) can be calculated using [`percentile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#percentile) or [`percentile_approx`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx.html#pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx)

- Approximate values for given percent_rank (percentile) values

  ```py
  df = df.groupBy('grp').agg(
      F.expr('percentile_approx(val, .25)').alias('lower_quartile_approx'),
      F.expr('percentile_approx(val, .75)').alias('upper_quartile_approx'),
      F.expr('percentile_approx(val, array(.25, .5, .75))').alias('all_quartiles_approx'),
      F.expr('percentile_approx(val, .9)').alias('90th_percentile_approx'),
  )
  df.show()
  # +---+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
  # |grp|lower_quartile_approx|upper_quartile_approx|all_quartiles_approx|90th_percentile_approx|
  # +---+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
  # |  A|                    1|                    3|           [1, 2, 3]|                     3|
  # |  B|                    4|                    6|           [4, 5, 6]|                     6|
  # +---+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
  ```
- Accurate values for given percent_rank (percentile) values:

  ```py
  df = df.groupBy('grp').agg(
      F.expr('percentile(val, .25)').alias('lower_quartile_acc'),
      F.expr('percentile(val, .75)').alias('upper_quartile_acc'),
      F.expr('percentile(val, array(.25, .5, .75))').alias('all_quartiles_acc'),
      F.expr('percentile(val, .9)').alias('90th_percentile_acc'),
  )
  df.show()
  # +---+------------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
  # |grp|lower_quartile_acc|upper_quartile_acc|all_quartiles_acc|90th_percentile_acc|
  # +---+------------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
  # |  A|               1.5|               2.5|  [1.5, 2.0, 2.5]| 2.8000000000000003|
  # |  B|               4.5|               5.5|  [4.5, 5.0, 5.5]|  5.800000000000001|
  # +---+------------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
  ```