# PySpark UDF on multi-level aggregated data; how can I properly generalize this

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I know of several ways to make calculations on an aggregation of a Spark dataframe column.  Too many... and it is not clear which is "best" or how they can properly be generalized as I would like.  I see [some StackOverflow solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845672/median-quantiles-within-pyspark-groupby) that conflict with [one](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html) or [another](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html) recommendation by Spark / Databricks themselves, but none do precisely what I want.

Below is a baby snippet of code showing what I am trying to do (multi-column aggregation using somewhat arbitrary calculation), and the ways *which work*, but which I cannot intelligently compare or assess:

#### Dataset

```py
df = sc.parallelize([
    [100, 'A', 1],
    [100, 'A', 2],
    [101, 'A', 3],
    [102, 'B', 4],
    [103, 'B', 5],
    [102, 'B', 6],
]).toDF(('id', 'grp', 'val'))
```

[image: Original Dataset]

#### Using [`applyInPandas`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas)

```py
def calc_q1(pddf):
  newcol = pddf.val.quantile(q=0.25)
  return pddf.assign(val_Q1 = newcol)

grp_df = df.groupBy('grp', 'id').applyInPandas(calc_q1, schema="grp string, id long, val long, val_Q1 double")
```

Which yields:

[image: ApplyInPandas Option]

Pros:

- All Pandas functions are now available

  - Arbitrary complexity / function
- This seems to be most recommended by Spark / Databricks

Cons:

- It seems hard-coding is required (i.e., I had to specify `val` in the `calc_q1` function).
- I cannot manage to return more than one value (in the later examples, you will see that a list of results is returned).
- It is a pain to have to provide the output schema and also forces some hard-coding.
- Each aggregate (each dataframe passed to the function) must fit in memory since a Pandas function is being called

  - This is not a concern for my work, but I'm curious: I would think this is a limit of all of the options I list, not just the Pandas option.

#### Using [Windowing](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.Window)

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

grp_window = Window.partitionBy('id', 'grp')
quantiles = F.expr('percentile_approx(val, array(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))')

grp_df = df.withColumn('med_val', quantiles.over(grp_window))
```

which yields:

[image: Using Windowing]

Pros:

- Using `functions.expr` seems almost as "open" and utilitarian as being able to rely upon all of Pandas.

Cons:

- It is a bit more laborious

  - Possibly also slower because of this??  I have not compared times.
- Using `Window` to perform aggregation somehow just feels "wrong".
- I still cannot perform any expression I would like, just any PySpark expression.

#### Using [`groupBy`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy)

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

quantiles = F.expr('percentile_approx(val, array(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))')

grp_df = df.groupBy('grp', 'id').agg(quantiles.alias('med_val'))
```

which yields:

[image: Using Group By]

Pros:

- This is what I already use for simpler calculations (ones that do not require UDFs or multi-level aggregations).
- It "feels" right, as the verbs that I am using `groupBy` and `agg` align exactly with the concepts and semantics of what I am doing.

Cons:

- I don't know, but since this is an "older" way of doing things, I feel there must be a reason why the newer methods were made.
- I still cannot perform any expression I would like, just any PySpark expression.

---

### What I ** Want to Achieve

I would **** like to find a way to be able to *pass arguments* to the aggregate function so that it could be generalized.  But I cannot figure out how.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```py
def calc_quants(pddf, col, quantcol, quants):
  pddf[quantcol] = pddf[col].quantile(q=quants) # Where `quants` is a list of values
  return pddf

grp_df = (df.groupBy('grp', 'id')
            .applyInPandas(calc_quants, val_quants, [0.25, 0.75],
                           schema="grp string, id long, val long, val_quants list"))
```

Being able to do something like what I have written above is my ultimate desire.  I list all the methods I have discovered because it seems none of them are capable of doing what I want.

Comment: please replace your images with real data so we can copy paste and use them.

Comment: @Steven The real data and the way to generate them are all there in the code.  Are you saying that you want me to remove the images altogether?  They are only there to make it easier for the eyes to view.